# I want to return status unable to do so when using groupBy

Tags: sql, rdbms

```
select a.NAME
from tableA a 
left outer join tableB b on a.id = b.xxx_id
where a.is_deleted = false
group by a.Name having count(b.id) = 0;
```

Using the above code, returns the list of names.

Results:
Row    NAME

```
     1      Name1 
     2.     Name2
     3.     Name3
```

I am using the below code to return name status.

```
select a.NAME, a.name_status
from tableA a 
left outer join tableB b on a.id = b.xxx_id
where a.is_deleted = false
group by a.Name having count(b.id) = 0;
```

However, when I add a.name_status it is giving me an error saying'a.name_status in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.

Desired output:
Row    NAME.    Name_status

```
     1      Name1      Pending
     2.     Name2      Expired
     3.     Name3.     Active
```

Comment: Yes, because you have not used it in an aggregate or a group by clause. What happens if you add it to your group by?

Comment: I added it, there was no output. group by a.name_status having count(b.id) = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current query I will guess that would you want could be done using *not exists*, although to be sure actual sample data would help clarify.

```
select a.NAME, a.name_status
from tableA a 
where a.is_deleted = false
and not exists (
  select * from tableB b
    where b.xxx_id = a.id
);
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANKS!! Can you please explain what the lines from not exists does?

Comment: The query in the *exists* is used to correlate rows against tableA based on the condition specified, ie, find rows matching `a.id` - using *not* basically says return rows from TableA only where there are no rows in tableB that match.